# Getting desktop (not Metro) Skype for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, skype, windows-store-app

I have Windows 8, and I want regular Skype, not Metro Skype. Metro Skype doesn't support many features that the desktop version does, and it's buggy.

I tried to go to http://beta.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/. When I hit "Get Skype for Windows 8," I'm redirected to the Windows Store to install Metro Skype.

How can I download and install normal Skype on Windows 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [original installer can be found here](http://www.skype.com/go/downloading-page).

- Download the setup file, right click on it and select **Properties**
- Select the **Compatibility Tab**
- Then check mark ***Run this program in Compatibility mode***
- Click  **Apply** and check if it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can download an offline installer here:

[Skype Offline Installer for Windows](http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-full)

No need to run it in compatibility mode, or be connected when installing - works perfectly.

I would recommend removing the Metro version, however - which I find quite annoying to use as it logs in and out randomly and renders you uncontactable - presumably because Metro has absolute control over it and kills it when your PC runs out of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

At the top hover mouse over get skype and select skype for windows desktop. Sign in and download.