# How can I send a file using Skype for Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8, skype, modern-ui

I tried to send some files to my friend using Skype for Modern UI. But there are no buttons for doing it! You can make a call, add more friends to a conversation, but you still can't send a file! I tried dragging it from the desktop, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, right clicking, …

Is there any solution for this or I have to [download and install the desktop version](https://superuser.com/questions/498785/getting-desktop-not-metro-skype-for-windows-8) and wait for Microsoft to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype (v1.5) now has button for sending files. [Details here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-8-from-Windows-Store/Update-1-5-File-transfer/td-p/1436191).

Answer (score 1):

Skype says they'll add this feature in an update coming soon.

[Details here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-8/File-sending-removed/m-p/1161084#M506)